# Landing page with a full screen image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am searching for a method to create a landing page with a full screen image (in a div, I persume). However, this landing page / div should be "scrollable". I think the tricky part is to make this div full screen on every device.

I found two websites, both have a landing page similar to what I am intending to do:
http://sailingcollective.com/ 
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/

Do you have any methods for doing this? Thanks :)

- Lasse

Answer (score 1):

Just use height: 100vh (viewport unit)

```
.divimage{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Fairly well supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I do not find this method to perform like on the links i mentioned. Is it perhaps js?

Comment: Very nice and helpful, thank you. But it seems Opera browser doesnt support this viewport unit... Firefox, Chrome and IE have shown the DIV background image nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in:

- Safari 3+
- Chrome Whatever+
- IE 9+
- Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
- Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

Comment: Thanks! But I do not get the same results as on the links I mentioned. Your code does not make this a fullscreen div with a full screen image, I think :)